# Make nonplanar graph

Tags: graph-theory

Let's say I have a planar graph. And I need to add as few edges as possible to make it non-planar.

[image: Panar and non-planar graphs]

So, from the picture: I have a graph №1 which is planar. Then I add an edge "e2", the graph looks non-planar but we can make it look like graph №3 which is planar again (graphs №2 and №3 are isomorphic, right?). So I add the last edge "e4" and I don't think it's possible to make graph №4 planar.

So my question is: is my reasoning correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The terminology 'planar graph' is shorthand for 'a graph that has a planar embedding' or 'has an embedding in the plane' or similar. The graph is an abstract object while the drawing of the graph is the embedding in the plane.

So when you say graph No2 'looks' non-planar, you mean that you have made a non-planar embedding, but you can re-arrange that to No3 which is indeed planar.

Finally, adding e4 gives you a graph which has **no** planar-embedding.